# Problem with fill matrix rows with zeroes

Tags: c++

I have to check if a given matrix have the same columns as rows, if not fullfill with zeroes

i have wrote the code for when rows are bigger ant it works, but for columns it shows core dumped

```
     if(filas < cols){
        //note filas means rows
        //reserve of memory
        int **nuevo = new int *[cols];
        for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
            nuevo[i] = new int [cols];


        //start new matrix to 0
        for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                nuevo[i][j] = 0;
        }

        //copy original matrix to new
        for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                nuevo[i][j] = m[i][j];
        }



        filas = cols;

        m = nuevo;

    }




actual output:
1 2 3 4 
2 4 6 8 
3 6 9 12 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

expected:
1 2 3 4 
2 4 6 8 
3 6 9 12 
0 0 0 0
```

when rows are bigger than columns:

```
original:
1 2 3  
2 4 6  
3 6 9  
4 8 12



output:
1 2 3 0 
2 4 6 0 
3 6 9 0 
4 8 12 0
```

Comment: You need to decide which index (first or second) is rows and which is columns, and stick to that. Your code seems to keep switching between them.

Comment: @interjay first index is rows and second is columns, so the rows are smaller tan columns and i want to "expand" total rows to total columns

Comment: @interjay The intention is to set `filas` to `cols` when `filas < cols`. However, I needed a while to get it but I couldn't find something wrong at third glance.

Comment: There occurs a memory leak when `m = nuevo;`. However, that's annoying but nothing what causes a crash.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Can you complete this sample to show how your crash can be (possibly) reproduced? I debugged by eyes but cannot see something critical (which does not mean that there isn't something).

Comment: There is still the option that the crash is caused by some other, non-exposed code. (It just happens in the exposed code but the reason is in prior executed code.)

Comment: yes rows horizontal and columns vertical @Scheff

Comment: https://pastebin.com/bZQLqjC2  full code

Comment: the problem is with the instantiation of `m` in your main() function..

Comment: I took your exposed code and made a [mcve]. I couldn't see anything else as what I already reported. [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe391457791b8e03). I still think the error is in the non-exposed code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash isn't happening in `llenar_0`, it's in `main`.  `filas` and `cols` are references when passed to `llenar_0`, but `m` is not.  The function creates `nuevo`, and assigns it to `m`, but that change is lost on return so `main` tries to use your original array with the new size.

Change:

```
void llenar_0(int **m, int &filas, int &cols){
```

to:

```
void llenar_0(int ** &m, int &filas, int &cols){
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the initialization of your rows which have to be equal to filas in you `main()`

**Change**

```
int filas = 3, cols = 4;
int **m = new int *[filas];
for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
    m[i] = new int [filas];
```

**into**

```
int filas = 3, cols = 4;
int **m = new int *[cols];
for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    m[i] = new int [filas];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to copy the given matrix to a square matrix -

```
int n = filas;
if ( filas < cols) {
    n = cols;
}

int **nuevo = new int *[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    nuevo[i] = new int [n];
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        nuevo[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < filas; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
        nuevo[i][j] = m[i][j];
    }
}
```

nuevo is the new matrix. Hope this helps, Thanks